# Insert random values in Oracle for primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a small table which I use to insert configuration data.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AGENT_GROUP_SEQ
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
 NOMINVALUE
 CACHE 20
/

CREATE TABLE AGENT_GROUP(
  ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(40 ) NOT NULL,
  STATUS VARCHAR2(30 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(30 ),
  DATE_ADDED DATE,
  LAST_MODIFIED DATE,
  DESCRIPTION CLOB
)
/

CREATE TRIGGER AGENT_GROUP_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON AGENT_GROUP
 REFERENCING  OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
 FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT AGENT_GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
/
```

I have a ID column which will be used for unique number. I managed to create sequence which will auto-generate ID value on every insert. But the problem is that I have too many insert and delete operations After some time I will reach sequence maximum value.

Is there any other way to generate random ID on every insert?

Comment: Are you actually experiencing the problem ? Or do you just think that `1.0000E+28` won't be enough ? You could theoretically generate random hash, but that would require a costly lookup if such hash doesn't exists in the table yet.

Comment: No but I would like to prevent it. Can you give more information about this solution?

Comment: I think that you would have other problems when you hit the limit. Please look at the number. Unless you're going to use, say more than `1.0000E+23` ids per day, you won't have any problems. At least not in your current life. :)

Comment: By my calculations, if you do one million transactions per second, you won't have to worry about running out of numbers for over 300 trillion years.  That seems like a pretty safe buffer for most applications.  In fact, I doubt that there are one billion transactions per second on all computers in the world.  If the numbers were used for all transactions, they would still last for many times longer than the stars in our galaxy.

Comment: What if I reach the SEQUENCE max value and I use CYCLE to instruct it to start again. I may have gaps int onto the table key values. What if I add option UNIQUE? Is it going to skip the exiting keys and add those which are not in use?

Comment: Option `UNIQUE` applies only in a multi RAC environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of UUID what u generate server side or with a db fuction.

http://lakenine.com/guid-values-as-primary-keys/

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger as well as your question is quite "verbose".
Not a real answer to your question but this code does exactly the same as your code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AGENT_GROUP_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT ON AGENT_GROUP
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.ID := NVL(:NEW.ID, AGENT_GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL);
END;
/
```

Simplify your life!

Regarding your sequence. You can make it `CYCLE` if you are concerned. 
Don't worry, even if your table contains only one column with this primary key the amount of data would be more than all available storage capacity over the world.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AGENT_GROUP_SEQ START WITH 1 NOMAXVALUE MINVALUE 1 CYCLE CACHE 20;
```

Comment: Can you give more information about CYCLE? Also can you edit the code in order to implement it, please?

Comment: Actually it was sarcasm from my side. The age of our universe is around 5e9 years and our sun will also shine for around 5e9 years which is 1.5e17 seconds. Having a sequence with max. value of 1e27 and assume each row would contain only **one single Byte** (which is not possible because your sequence number already occupies up to 15 Bytes) you would fill a **10GByte disc every single second** for the lifetime of our sun.